# Adding images from array to Dom with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a multidimensional array

```
 var pics [
       ['Tim', 'blue','asset/images/pic.jpeg']
       ['Jane', 'red','asset/images/pic2.jpeg'] 
       ]
```

How can I pull pics[0][2]  (pic.jpeg) and append/push it to a html element 
    with 
    the ID pictures. (#pictures)

What I thought the code would be was

```
       $('#pictures').append('src', pics[0][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you want to create a new image within `pictures`? I don't really know because you posted an incomplete question using invalid syntax and part of the description mixed in with the code.

Anyway, given that assumption...

```
$("#pictures").append(`<img src="${pics[0][2]}">`);
```

or without jQuery...

```
document.querySelector("#pictures")
        .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<img src="${pics[0][2]}">`)
```

Comment: Yes that what I want to do

Comment: @GabePerry please edit your question with the link below to make it more clear that's what your trying to do rather than let people guess!

Comment: I don't know how much more simple I could have made it.  Thanks for the help anyway.